# How to keep the line inside the plot using abline?

Tags: r, plot, line

I have a quick question. I want to add a horizontal and a vertical line in my plot. I tried using abline() for that, but my line exceeds the plot area. Reason being: I added par(xpd = T) to be able to add my legend outside of my plot. Is there another way to add a line just inside in the plot?

R-version:            3.6.1

Platform:             x86_64_w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: i think typically it is good practice only to use xpd when you need to (eg, in `text(..., xpd = TRUE)`) rather than setting it globally. but you can also try `abline(.., xpd = FALSE)` if you have already set xpd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not know that I could use the xpd argument with abline as well. So rawr's comment solved my problem :)